# Generate points from 2D fractal noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, noise, procedural-generation

I'm using layered Perlin noise to generate 2D points, using the method from https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/#trees. However, I would like the point's coordinates to not be `int`s, but `float`s. To accomplish this I implemented a `resolution` variable:

```
List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2> ();
int res = 10;
int R = 2;
for (int yc = 0; yc < height*res; yc++) {
    for (int xc = 0; xc < width*res; xc++) {
        float max = 0;
        for (int yn = yc - R; yn <= yc + R; yn++) {
            for (int xn = xc - R; xn <= xc + R; xn++) {
                float e = pointsMap.GetClampedValue((float)xn/res, (float)yn/res);
                if (e > max) { max = e; }
            }
        }
        if (pointsMap.GetClampedValue((float)xc/res, (float)yc/res) == max) {
            points.Add (new Vector2((float)xc/res, (float)yc/res));
        }
    }
}
```

`pointsMap.GetClampedValue()` returns a `float` from 0-1.

With a width and height of 100, a resolution of 10, and `R = 2`, a total amount of 25 million `for` loops are executed. While the code within the loops is far from optimised, the code is executed within a reasonable amount of time with the above settings. However, as the resolution, width, height, and `R` increase, the execution time goes up way too high.

In the original function, the author left a comment saying that there are more efficient algorithms than this. Would anyone know an algorithm that is efficient, fast, and where this resolution implementation would be possible?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159318/faster-algorithm-than-nested-loops, not sure but take a look.

Comment: Your code has resolution^2 more work to do so it will run orders of magnitude slower for even small increases in resolution or size. It would help to know what you're using the points for - I can think of a simple alternative, but it isn't appropriate for certain applications

Comment: @Pikalek I'm using the points for object placement in a procedural terrain generator. I've tried using Poisson disk sampling, but I need the algorithm to return the same points every time a certain area is accessed, if that makes sense - hence my use of a noise map

Comment: @Jonan no, that doesn't make sense to me. As with Perlin noise, if you use the same ransom seed for an area, you'll get the same Poisson disk sampling for the area. Bit if you still want to stick to Perlin noise, I'll list modifications that might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to with something that hews close to the tutorial you linked, but you need float coords rather than decimal coords, the simplest solution is to simple add a random value in the range [0,1):

```
Random rng = new Random(regionSeed);
List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2> ();
for (int yc = 0; yc < height; yc++) {
  for (int xc = 0; xc < width; xc++) {
    double max = 0;
    // there are more efficient algorithms than this
    for (int yn = yc - R; yn <= yc + R; yn++) {
      for (int xn = xc - R; xn <= xc + R; xn++) {
        double e = value[yn][xn];
        if (e > max) { max = e; }
      }
    }
    if (value[yc][xc] == max) {
      list.add( new Vector2(xc+rng.NextDouble(),yc+rng.NextDouble()) );
    }
  }
}
```